# Serialization / Normalizing of data to JSON: How to programmatically change the output mapping?

Tags: php, json, serialization, symfony

I have the following controller/action:

```
 public function messagesAction()
  {
    $encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
    $normalizers = array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer());
    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
    $message = $this->getDoctrine()
      ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Message')
      ->findAll();
    $response = new Response($serializer->serialize($message, 'json')); 
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
  }
}
```

which sends the following json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "iam": 1,
        "youare": 2,
        "lat": 50.8275853,
        "lng": 4.3809764,
        "msgbody": "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "iam": 1,
        "youare": 2,
        "lat": 50.8307348,
        "lng": 4.3734823,
        "msgbody": "What up?"
    }
]
```

I don't have a named key and it makes hard for my Javascript fw (Ember) to get some objects.

I'd like to change the Json output to:

```
[
    {
      "message": {
        "id": "1",
        "iam": "male",
        "youare": "female",
        "lat": "50.8307348"
      }
    }
]
```

I know there are regular expressions I could play with but I don't really know where. As you see I am using the standard out of the box serializer (that was the only way I could return valid Json). Does it come with options to do what I want? (bonus: I'd also to manipulate the data before I send them..)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this kind of problem, I've develop a sf2 bundle to export data to differents formats, and you can customize your output just with twig templates

https://github.com/IDCI-Consulting/ExporterBundle

Hope this will be usefull.

Comment: Could you provide some more info on how to resolve the specific problem? (as I see the bundle is like a complete replacement of Serializer bundle..)